# java.sql.SQLException: error occurred during batching: batch must be either executed or cleared

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jdbc

I am getting

> java.sql.SQLException: error occurred during batching: batch must be
>   either executed or cleared

in the below code. I want to execute two queries.

```
String sql_query="insert into m_status values(20,'test');select * from m_user";
String query1 = sql_query.toUpperCase();

String[] results = query1.split(";");

stmt = conn1.createStatement();
conn1.setAutoCommit(false); 
for (int i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    if(results[i].startsWith("SELECT")) {
        rs1 = stmt.executeQuery(results[i]);
    }
    else if(results[i].startsWith("INSERT")){
        stmt.addBatch(results[i]);
    }
}
int [] updateCounts = stmt.executeBatch();
conn1.commit(); 
if (rs1 != null)
    rs1.close();
if (stmt != null)
    stmt.close();
if (conn1 != null)
    conn1.close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use two statements, one for select queries and another one for updates. `executeQuery` checks if there batches for that `Statament`, and if so throws that error. Also, wrap your queries in a `try-catch-finally` block and close the resources in the finally block. As it is, your code could lead to connection leaks.

Answer (score 1):

You test if your query begins with a uppercase SELECT and it's not the case. So your two queries are added to the batch statement.
You could use

```
com.mysql.jdbc.StringUtils.startsWithIgnoreCase(results[i], "select");
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use [`PreparedStatement#executeBatch()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch%28%29) when using batches.

Also make sure you execute

```
int n = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```