# Java & SQL - Error when batch processing, batch must be either executed or cleared

Tags: java, sql, oracle, prepared-statement

I'm reading a lot of data and want to inset them in a database. So far, not a big deal and everything was working fine using a prepared statement and firing it for every row. 
Now I switched to batch processing for better performance and get an error:
     `java.sql.SQLException: Fehler bei Stapelverarbeitung aufgetreten: batch must be either executed or cleared`
The only information I found on SO about this specific error is this question [dealing with different types of sql stements for one batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11030081/java-sql-sqlexception-error-occurred-during-batching-batch-must-be-either-exec).
However, that's not what I'm doing, here's the code:

```
    @Override
    public void addRow(String[] row) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
        PreparedStatement s = q.getStatement();
        for (int i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
            s.setString(i + 1, row[i]);
        }
        s.addBatch();

    }

    @Override
    public void done() {
        try {
            DatabaseUtils.execute(q); //Error is thrown here!
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Additional information: q is simple wrapper for PreparedStatements which allwos me to load it easier, after the first `getStatement()` call no further changes to the statement are possible. The statment is a simple INSERT like `INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)`
DatabaseUtils.execute does nothing else as `query.getStatement().execute();`.
Database is an Oracle Database V10.205, JDK 1.6´, Driver is ojdbc6

Can someone please explain me why the error is thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe

> `DatabaseUtils.execute` does nothing else as
>   `query.getStatement().execute();`

is the problem here. Try changing it to `query.getStatement().executeBatch()` or create a new method `DatabaseUtils.executeBatch` that will do that.